# Rails undefined method 'model_name' for nil:nilClass with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have in my **orders/edit.html.erb** a form that begins like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@reservation, @order] do |f| %>
```

**Orders Controller:**

```
def edit
  @reservation = Reservation.find_by_id(params[:reservation_id])
  @order       = Order.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

**Association:**

Reservation `:has_one` Order

**Routes:**

```
resources :reservations do
  resources :orders 
end
```

If my path resembles something like `/reservations/10/orders/10/edit` I end up getting an error from Rails saying `NoMethodError in Orders#edit` and `undefined method 'model_name' for nil:NilClass`

When I create a new order the form works perfectly fine so not sure why i'm getting an error all of a sudden, can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Change `find_by_id` to `find` ... could be wrong, but my guess is that the row does not exist; if so, `find` will blow up (properly, as you don't want to continue in this case anyway); `find_by_id` will just set things to `nil`, which will non-deterministically blow up somewhere along the way.

Comment: That definitely worked, please answer below so i can mark it as a solution! thanks so much! By the way, is there a way for find_by_id to 'blow up' so I can get the same error? @GoGoCarl

Comment: Thanks.  See below for details on your second question.  `find_by_id` won't ever blow up, it'll always return `nil` if the record isn't found. But you can handle that case manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current implementation is prone to failure when the URL supplied either a reservation ID or an order ID that is not valid.  Two ways to handle this:

First, let Rails do it for you:

```
def edit
  @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
  @order       = Order.find(params[:id])
end
```

This will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error, which, in production, should lead users to your 404 page.

If you'd prefer to keep `find_by_id` and handle this manually, or to rescue from this error in a different way, you can do:

```
def edit
  @reservation = Reservation.find_by_id(params[:reservation_id])
  @order       = Order.find_by_id(params[:id])

  if @reservation.nil? || @order.nil?
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.new # Or, do something else
  end
end
```

That would yield the same result as above ... just more code.